# SeaBios overrides boot; Error: no bootable device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

So I did all the steps to dev on my acre 15.6 chromebook, installed this, and reset. The moment I reset, SeaBios pops up and says no bootable disks found.

I assume that my entire disk has been wiped and I can't get Ubuntu to write and boot over seabios. I've been at this for the past 36 hours and I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you still have it/want to fix it?